# In Sex and the City how do the women actually make a living?

Tags: sex-and-the-city-tv

In the Sex and the City TV series and movies it seems that the four women spend all their time dating, shopping, meeting each other, or otherwise pursuing personal time. How do they actually earn enough to live their lifestyles?

Answer (score 18):

Charlotte is fortunate enough to have men who will give her money (Trey from divorce, Harry from marriage). At the start of the series, she works in a gallery.

Carrie is a writer for the New York Star and in later series writes for Vogue.

Miranda is a successful lawyer, becoming a partner in later episodes or the first movie (can't remember which).

Samantha works in PR and is very well regarded.

Comment: Carrie earns $4 per word at Vogue. [This article](http://thoughtcatalog.com/2011/carrie-bradshaws-budget-in-real-numbers/) makes a  good analysis of her budget.

Comment: @fdisk The Question wasn't if the character's occupations are realistic to their lifestyles (although that might be what is implied, but it isn't actually worded as such), but just what their occupations were. Interesting breakdown though!

Answer (score -3):

They are all successful working women. Carrie also wrote some books and is writing her column for the newspaper, the Storyline. It think, the business of them isn´t so important in this show. The main-story should be their private relationships while living in New York.

Comment: "They are all successful working Women," doesn't answer the question.